# Configure VSCode to execute different task

Tags: configuration, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a TypeScript project in Visual Studio Code with the following task:

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",

  // The command is tsc.
  "command": "tsc",

  // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur. 
  "showOutput": "silent",

  // Under windows use tsc.exe. This ensures we don't need a shell.
  "windows": {
    "command": "tsc"
  },

  "isShellCommand": true,

  // args is the program to compile.
  "args": [],

  // use the standard tsc problem matcher to find compile problems in the output.
  "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

This works well when we hit "Ctrl + Shift + B" to build.

Is it possible to have another task that when we press "F5" to run/debug it runs a command through the command line?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### TASK RUNNERS VS DEBUGGING PLUS LIVE PREVIEW

#### Task Runner

Currently, for VSCode version 0.5.0, you can use a task runner, identified in your task.json, to run multiple tasks using the same runner.  At this time, configuring different tasks runners is not possible.  For example, if you were using Gulp as a task runner you might have something like the following:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "gulp",
"isShellCommand": true,
"args": [
    "--no-color"
],
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "serve-dev",
        "isBuildCommand": false,
        "isTestCommand": true,
        "showOutput": "always",
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "taskName": "serve-build",
        "isBuildCommand": false,
        "isTestCommand": true,
        "showOutput": "always",
        "args": []
    }
```

Now the Gulp tasks would be defined and coded with Gulp but the important thing to note is the  `isBuildCommand` and `isTestCommand` as these correlate to `CTRL+SHFT+B and CTRL+SHFT+T` respectively.  So these two tasks would be available as keyboard shortcuts.  In addition, if you add additional tasks they will each be enumerated and accessible with `CTRL+SHFT+P then type "RUN" then select "TASK: Run Task".` Each of your tasks with be enumerated, listed and selectable.

The following code just demonstrates how eash VSCode task is related to a task runner task:

```
//automate build node server start and restart on changes
gulp.task('serve-build', ['optimize'], function () {

serve(false /* is Build */);

});

//automate dev node server start and restart on changes
gulp.task('serve-dev', ['inject'], function () {

serve(true /* is Dev */);

});
```

#### Debugging

Now for debugging with Node.js or Mono you have similar options. You will want to configure your `launch.json` or press the `'gear icon'`. You can set the debugger to `debug` or `run` your app and use the VSCode `'F5'` or `PLAY` button or menu's to start/stop/restart your app. From there you just use your favorite browser and access the server of your app. You can also use an external debugger to 'attach' to your app.  Following is a sample launch.json:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
// List of configurations. Add new configurations or edit existing ones.
// ONLY "node" and "mono" are supported, change "type" to switch.
"configurations": [
    {
        // Name of configuration; appears in the launch configuration drop down menu.
        "name": "Debug src/server/app.js",
        // Type of configuration. Possible values: "node", "mono".
        "type": "node",
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the program.
        "program": "src/server/app.js",
        // Automatically stop program after launch.
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        // Command line arguments passed to the program.
        "args": [],
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the working directory of the program being debugged. Default is the current workspace.
        "cwd": ".",
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the runtime executable to be used. Default is the runtime executable on the PATH.
        "runtimeExecutable": null,
        // Optional arguments passed to the runtime executable.
        "runtimeArgs": [],
        // Environment variables passed to the program.
        "env": { },
        // Use JavaScript source maps (if they exist).
        "sourceMaps": false,
        // If JavaScript source maps are enabled, the generated code is expected in this directory.
        "outDir": null
    },
    {
        // Name of configuration; appears in the launch configuration drop down menu.
        "name": "Run src/server/app.js",
        // Type of configuration. Possible values: "node", "mono".
        "type": "node",
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the program.
        "program": "src/server/app.js",
        // Automatically stop program after launch.
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        // Command line arguments passed to the program.
        "args": [],
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the working directory of the program being debugged. Default is the current workspace.
        "cwd": ".",
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the runtime executable to be used. Default is the runtime executable on the PATH.
        "runtimeExecutable": null,
        // Optional arguments passed to the runtime executable.
        "runtimeArgs": [],
        // Environment variables passed to the program.
        "env": { },
        // Use JavaScript source maps (if they exist).
        "sourceMaps": false,
        // If JavaScript source maps are enabled, the generated code is expected in this directory.
        "outDir": null
    },
    {
        "name": "Attach",
        "type": "node",
        // TCP/IP address. Default is "localhost".
        "address": "localhost",
        // Port to attach to.
        "port": 5858,
        "sourceMaps": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice the `'stopOnEntry'` property for the `RUN and DEBUG` setups.  This is how you can use the debugger to run or debug the app.  From there you would just use the debug `'PLAY'` button combined with the debug menu to select the appropriate configuration.

#### Live Preview

Live Preview is not currently implemented in VSCode.  Two of my favorites so far are [BrowserSync](http://www.browsersync.io/) and [Live.JS](http://livejs.com/).

#### GULP TASK WITH NODEMON

Following is some code that may help point the way to configuring Gulp to run a node.js server.  Remember that Gulp tasks can require other tasks to run first. In the code above, the Gulp task `"serve-build"` requires another task `"optimize"` to run first.  `"optimize" can require other tasks to run and so forth.`You can chain these tasks so that your top level tasks run all of your sub-level tasks.  Following is a function that's executed from a Gulp task in the gulpfile.js setup:

```
function serve(isDev) {
log('Start pre processes and node server...');
var nodeOptions = {
    script: config.nodeServer,
    delayTime: 3,
    env: {
        'PORT': port,
        'NODE_ENV': isDev ? 'dev' : 'build'
    },
    watch: [config.server]
};

return $.nodemon(nodeOptions)
    .on('restart', ['vet'], function (ev) {
        log('*** nodemon restarted');
        log('files changes on restart:\n' + ev);
        setTimeout(function () {
            browserSync.notify('reloading now ...');
            browserSync.reload({ stream: false });
        }, config.browserReloadDelay);
    })
    .on('start', function () {
        log('*** nodemon started');
        startBrowserSync('isDev');
    })
    .on('crash', function () {
        log('*** nodemon crashed: script crashed for some reason');
    })
    .on('exit', function () {
        log('*** nodemon exited cleanly');
    });

}
```

So the following Gulp tasks actually just run this function which runs nodemon via the Gulp nodemon plugin to make `production / "build"` or `test / "dev"` builds using a parameter variable:

```
//automate build node server start and restart on changes
gulp.task('serve-build', ['optimize'], function () {

serve(false /* is Build */);

});

//automate dev node server start and restart on changes
gulp.task('serve-dev', ['inject'], function () {

serve(true /* is Dev */);

});
```

#### MAPPING GULP TASKS TO THE VSCODE TASK RUNNER

Finally, you can map your top-level Gulp tasks like `"serve-dev"`
and `"serve-build"` by adding entries to your VSCode tasks.json and using `isBuildCommand` and `isTestCommand` to map to `CTRL+SHFT+B` and `CTRL+SHFT-T` respectively.

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "gulp",
"isShellCommand": true,
"args": [
    "--no-color"
],
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "serve-dev",
        "isBuildCommand": false,
        "isTestCommand": true,
        "showOutput": "always",
        "args": []
    },
    {
        "taskName": "serve-build",
        "isBuildCommand": false,
        "isTestCommand": true,
        "showOutput": "always",
        "args": []
    }
```

#### VSCode Output

VSCode also has a task.json property to show output of your running tasks in VSCode. This will open the `OUTPUT` window of VSCode just like using `SHFT+CTRL+H` or selecting the menu `VIEW` then selecting `SHOW OUTPUT`. At this time the output window does not display color.

Just set `"showOutput"` to `always`. Perhaps this could replace your need to start a terminal/command line window thats running your node app.  You can also set this property to `never` or `silent` depending on your needs.  You can find more info about these properties in the VSCode [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks).

You can also `STOP` a running task by with `CTRL-SHFT-B` or `CTRL-SHFT-T` or use the menus after starting a task.

Finally, if you must compile your code and run the app in a terminal I think you will need to use a script/batch file in your task.json configuration that runs your task runner and then starts your node server.

Comment: So it seems that my only option right now would be to create 2 gulp tasks and have 1 of the tasks to compile my TypeScript code and the other task to run a command through the command prompt window, correct? Basically I wanted to press F5 to run a command that would launch the app in a console.

Comment: I think what you are trying to accomplish is compile your typescript and run a node server with the 'F5' run debugger key. This will not work as the debugger is separate from the task runner.  However, you can configure your task runner to compile and subsequently run your node server with a single task shortcut CTRL+SHFT+B or CTRL+SHFT+T. Tasks can be configured to run only after other tasks have run and as far as Gulp is concerned there are numerous plugins you can use like http://nodemon.io/ and https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-nodemon .  I've tried to add some code to the answer above.

Comment: No, I'm not trying to launch node server. I want to configure F5 to run execute a program through command line that would deploy my project to a different device. The only options I see when configuring task runner is "node" and "mono" that's why I'm asking how I could change it to execute a batch file or other command of my choice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use gulp and just do the typescript compilation then a simple way is to go to terminal and run  **`tsc -w <filename.ts>`**, no need of tasks.json.
It watches for file changes and converts them to js files.

Then whenever you hit 'F5' it should run the updated js file pointed in launch.json.

If you want tsc to convert mutiple ts files you can also add **tsconfig.json** in your application root with "rootdir", then just run **`tsc -w`** and F5 to execute application.

sample tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "ES5",
        "outDir": "<js dir>",
        "rootDir": "<point to all ts dir>"
    }
```

}

Answer (score -1):

I believe this was solved by a later feature, namely the pre launch task.  You can have it run a task before it launches node/Chrome with F5.

http://tstringer.github.io/javascript/vscode/nodejs/gulpjs/2015/10/14/vscode-prelaunchtask.html

Comment: Dead link, as of this comment