# Run in browser with VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I run my HTML in a browser using VS Code? I've tried to find instructions online but I cannot find a solution.

I tried adding this to my `tasks.json`:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",

"command": "explorer",

"windows": {
    "command": "explorer.exe"
},

"args": ["index.html"]
}
```

But if I `ctrl + shift + b` it just opens my documents folder instead of the browser. I tried the steps here: [How to view my HTML code in browser with Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039512/how-to-view-my-html-code-in-browser-with-visual-studio-code) but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039512/how-to-view-my-html-code-in-browser-with-visual-studio-code ??

Comment: Yeah. That's the link I provided in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I use Gulp, NodeMon and BrowserSync with VSC Tasks and Debugger and this works really well on multiple PC's and devices.  This can take a bit of setup though.
[Link to Stack Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31973700/configure-vscode-to-execute-different-task/31991499#31991499)

At the time of this writing, recently an extension called Debugger for Chrome was developed by MS. I find this debugger very useful and flexible. One of it's features allows starting a debugging instance in Chrome for the client side app.  Without break points it will just load the client side app in the chrome browser.  I frequently switch between this client debugger and the native Chrome Dev tools.

[Debugger for Chrome](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome)

There also an extension I haven't tried called View In Browser.

[View In Browser](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qinjia.view-in-browser)